# CSS Background Image desde una base de datos MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, apache

Por poner un ejemplo, para colocar una imagen como background usando CSS, usando este parámetro:

```
body {
background-image: url("paper.gif");
}
```

Pero quisiera que esa imagen se extraiga desde una base de datos MySQL, con la intención de hacer páginas web dinámicas, usando pocos archivos web HTML y así cada vez que se visite una página dinámica, cambie no solo los textos sino también la imagen de fondo. (Algo así como sucede con Wordpress).

Alguien que me pueda apoyar con esto. Muchísimas gracias. Saludos.

Comment: Eso se hace mediante css, te recomiendo tenerlo externo al archivo .css y así llamarlo en tus paginas...

Comment: ¿No hay otra forma de hacer que el archivo extraiga la imagen de forma dinámica sin recurrir al BLOB? Esto es porque mi hosting me da una cantidad limitada en la DB y si me pasara de ese límite no podría actualizar mi DB, lo que ese método se volvería inviable para mí. Si conoces de un método muy similar a la utilizada cuando extraes una imagen de manera normal usando MySQL, mucho te lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo tu pregunta.

Lo que quieres es almacenar la imagen en la base de datos, y luego leerla con CSS, es posible.

Para ello tienes que usar un campo BLOB, te recomiendo echarle un ojo a [esta página](https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/2481-almacenar-archivos-en-campos-blob-con-php-y-mysql/).

El campo BLOB te permite almacenar datos binarios de gran tamaño en la DB, yo en lo personal preferiría no usarlos porque es añadirle peso a la DB de forma innecesaria.

Si finalmente lo haces, y vas a cambiar la imagen constantemente, no añadas la regla en el archivo CSS, sino que lo hagas en una función onload con JavaScript y añadiendole un número aleatorio para que la caché del navegador no te impida visualizar la nueva imagen, te enseño un fragmento de un código que tengo para que lo entiendas:

```
document.getElementById("title-logo-div").style.backgroundImage = "url(get-user-img.php?" + rand_img + ")";
```

Donde rand_img equivale a:

```
let rand_img = Math.random();
```

Comment: Pero tu aporte no resuelve la duda, no muestra como obtenerlo de la base de datos y mostrar la imagen

Comment: Tienes razón, sin embargo en el enlace que he incluído se explica detalladamente, no veía necesario repetirlo. No sé si es un error muy grave, si es así mis disculpas.

Comment: La idea de las respuestas es incluir aquí la solución, deja el enlace solo como referencia

Comment: De hecho, la idea no es precisamente crear un BLOB en la DB, sino más bien es que yo aloje la imagen en el hosting, se haga una instrucción desde PHP que jale esa imagen. Más o menos como ocurre con las imágenes estáticas cuando se configuran en MySQL, solo que de forma dinámica y desde CSS3. Como ocurre con Wordpress. No sé si me explico.